# Bug atualizando foto

Tags: bug

Não consigo atualizar minha foto de perfil através de upload. Faço o upload, a foto nova aparece, mas quando clico pra salvar apenas para esta comunidade (Stack Overflow em Português), aparece o erro:

[image: Bugue]

Comment: "erro incomum", kkkkk

Comment: Por essa você não esperava não é mesmo?

Comment: Deve ser a Roberta me trollando.